# SSL Certificate not valid here

Tags: support

Just coming here from the main page chrome smashed my face with a large yellow screen: "The ssl certificate is not valid for this site"

Unfortunatly I didn't have the quick though to snip it, but I got a snippet from my "omnibox", aka. navigation bar:

[image]

It seems that chrome doesn't like the dot between `meta` and  `scifi`:

[image]

Comment: If I change the URL to `https` in Firefox, I get a similar warning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually valid behaviour; [RFC 2818](ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc2818.txt) specifies that only a single level of subdomain matching is permitted for wildcard SSL certs:

> Names may contain the wildcard character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`.

Any browser that successfully matches more than one level is therefore non-compliant.

It seems that this is a technical misconfiguration with SE itself; they shouldn't be using a single-level wildcard cert on this domain.

(Do I win a prize?)

Comment: Yes you win a non-rep upvote :) I hope they fix this though... maybe ima drop this link in the Tavern on Meta..

Comment: It seems the root issue is, that you may not create wildcard certs for `meta.*.stackexchange.com` and the like since [RFC 6125 (sect. 6.4.3)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3)

Answer (score 1):

Uber-Meta has some answers in stash. To make it short: Switching to full SSL is scheduled. It's supposed to happen in the memetic 6-8 weeks and meta-domains will probably be changed.

[Balpha has written a short answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230302/invalid-ssl-certificate-on-meta-stackexchange-com-cant-log-in-without-ssl/230303#230303) where he refers us to [Nick Craver's Blog-Post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).

There Nick elaborates the difficulties of going to HTTPS. So in short:

Known problem, in progress, keep calm and pop a beer or something ;)