# SSL Certificate Still Invalid

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

Was a little surprised to see this screen when I attempted to switch to Meta:

[image]

I know that this was already commented on ([SSL Certificate not valid here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4903/15672)), but that was about a year ago. Has no progress been made on this issue, or is this a regression?

Comment: Was this via a link somewhere on the network, or did you type that in? Because all links on the network should've been converted.

Comment: @SQB - check the date of the question :P

Comment: @Mithrandir app only shows "Edited 17 hr. ago" :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta links have been switched to scifi.meta.stackexchange.com, and now have a valid HTTPS certificate. See [this post on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/). This should probably be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now (but my flag requesting it was declined :/).

Comment: Ask and ye shall (eventually, sometimes) receive.

Answer (score 5):

At least as of right now, visiting meta sites over SSL is "not supported". The most recent information I could find on meta.SE was from last year, and there doesn't appear to have been any change since then.

The technical problem is the way the domain names are formatted breaks the wildcard SSL certificates. The certificate is for `*.stackexchange.com`, which matches `site.stackexchange.com` but doesn't match `meta.site.stackexchange.com`.

In order to make things work they need to restructure the domain names so that, e.g.

```
meta.scifi.stackexchange.com ===> scifi.meta.stackexchange.com
```

Once that's done, a certificate for `*.meta.stackexchange.com` will work, but I assume that's not a trivial change so they haven't gotten around to it.

See:

[Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

[Untrusted connection when visiting per-site meta over SSL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/untrusted-connection-when-visiting-meta-stack-exchange-sites)

[This blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Comment: Interesting... Because I did not put https in the address bar. I just clicked the meta link from the navigation menu.

Comment: @JDB Which link? And do you have any addons like HTTPSEverywhere installed?

Comment: @AnnaLear - Took some retracing of my steps, but I figured it out... I followed the first link from [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7296/15672) (which had the https protocol explicitly defined) which took me to the main site. I finished reading the content, then clicked the "Meta" link from the "Help" menu. I'm guessing it's a relative link because it adopted the https protocol, resulting in the error message in my post. If https is not supported in Meta, then the nav link should probably not be relative.

Comment: I've corrected the links in that post; that is annoying.